# Asynchronous Ajax request in extjs

Tags: ajax

In my application I have 7 grid editors. And user have provision to save or update all grid editors at once.

For save and update I made Ajax requests to different JSP's.

But the problem is data is not saving as per order the user has fed the input to grid.

If I give alert between any of this function then it is saving properly.

Earlier when I am using JavaScript I made Ajax request using xmlhttp object and there is option while passing parameters:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajaxCode/PMS/pmsInputScreen/SavePipeGroup.jsp",false);
```

If we changed this false to true the same problem occurred. Is there any property in `Ext.ajax.request` like this?

Comment: what version of ExtJs you using?

Comment: Try with callbacks in Ext.ajax.request

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Ajax